# Create a set of tuples from dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the dataframe as below:

```
 Position  x  y
    A      1  2
    B      2  5
    C      1  4
    D      0  5
```

I am trying to create a set of tuples like this:

```
set={'A':(1,2),'B':(2,5),'C':(1,4),'D':(0,5)}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.iterrows()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) method as following.

```
>>> set = {row.Position: (row.x, row.y) for i, row in df.iterrows()}
>>> print(set)
{'A': (1, 2), 'B': (2, 5), 'C': (1, 4), 'D': (0, 5)}
```

Comment: @HuyềnThương,  I am glad I could help. If answer is correct, please, consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.